# When calling a method, when to reference the class, and when to reference the object?

Tags: c#

So, when you're calling a method, how do you know when to reference the object, and how do you know when to reference the class? For example:

Why is it

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
```

and not

```
myStr.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

Comment: You can't use `myStr.IsNullOrEmpty();` unless you have declared an extension method! What's your mean? Your question is unclear.

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` is a _static_ method.  With static methods, you call them using the name of the class.  If the method is not static, then you call it using the instance variable.  In your example `myStr.IsNullOrEmpty();` will not compile since `IsNullOrEmpty` is static.

Comment: If `myStr` is null, what do you think `myStr.IsNullOrEmpty()` will do?

Comment: @DourHighArch The code doesn't compile, so one couldn't comment on what it would do when run.

Comment: @DourHighArch if you wrote your own extension method than it can check for null just fine... (as Servy said `string.IsNullOrEmpty` can't be called that way). Indeed there are different opinions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592029/handling-null-in-extension-method) whether extensions should throw on null argument or not, but it is perfectly legal from language point of view to not get NRE on `myStr.IsNullOrEmpty()` extension call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the method is static - reference the class.

When the method is not static - the instance.

(There are other cases such as extension methods... But I think this is what you're looking for.)

---

For the case you brought: See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) under "syntax":

> public **static** bool IsNullOrEmpty [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 1):

static methods do not need an instance of the class to be performed with, IsNullOrEmpty() is such a one -you prefix it with the classname.

Some static methods (Extensions) can be used to extend classes which you did not write and "add onto" the Methods usable with a class.

Example

```
// must be a top lvl class to enable declaring extension method
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool IsSet(this string s)
      => s != null && s.Trim().Length > 0;
}
```

Which then will be callable by `if ("blablubb".IsSet()) ...` or by `if (StringExt.IsSet("blablubb")) ...`.

So the short answer would be read the API (sometimes shortened to RTFM) and look at the signatures.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

is no Extension method, its simply a static method that has no dependencys on using the string instances internal data - so it was declared static on the string class - something alike to

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string s)
{
    // look up implementation here:
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs
}
```

[link to IsNullOrEmpty](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#23a8597f842071f4)

Answer (score 1):

> how do you know when to reference the object, and how do you know when to reference the class?

by looking at method declaration. if instance method is declared (a normal method) you should call method in this way.

```
myStr.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

if static method is declared (method signature contains `static` keyword) you should call method in this way.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
```

where `String` is name of class and `IsNullOrEmpty` is name of static method inside that class.

sometimes static methods are declared as extension methods (first parameter of static method is prefixed with `this` keyword) so you can call them in two identical ways.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);    
myStr.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

assuming `IsNullOrEmpty` is extension method, both syntaxes will work perfectly fine and are identical (note that such method does not exist in .Net framework but you can write your own).